# SPI configuation as master

Tags: stm32, spi, keil, nucleo

I need to configure SPI_1 as master in Nucleo STM32F103RB. Here's what I did so far (Keil uvision 4).

```
// Configuring GPIOs


// SPI_SCK
GPIOA_CRL |= 0x00A00000; //Alternate function push-pull

// SPI_MOSI
GPIOA_CRL |= 0xA0000000; //Alternate function push-pull

// SPI_MISO
GPIOA_CRL |= 0x04000000; //Input floating
```

However I need to set nSS for multiple slaves. How do I do that? Which GPIO pins should I use to connect nSS pins to multiple slaves.

Also how many maximum slaves can I attach?

Answer (score 2):

You can use any GPIO. Just configure them as outputs and  manually set their state to choose the slave. There is no other way for the multiple CS lines.

Comment: Should I set GPIOs as Alternate function output push-pull?

Comment: No digital output. You can't control them using the SPI hardware (only one line is supported)